# Собираем дату в дату UNIX

Tags: php

Подскажите как собрать дату в стиле UNIX(от 1.01.70 в секундах) на php, есть входящие данные:
1) День
2) Месяц
3) Год
4) Час
5) Минута

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php